# open iOS iPad simulator with React Native by default

Tags: react-native, ios-simulator

By default, simulator is iPhone when you test React Native app.
I know there is the --simulator flag :

```
react-native run-ios --simulator 'iPad 2'
```

Ok, but how to simulate ipad by default without this flag...

Thank you !

Answer (score 12):

You could as well use "scripts" part of package.json:

```
"scripts": {
  "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start",
  "ipad": "react-native run-ios --simulator 'iPad Air'"
}
```

And then run: `npm run ipad`

Comment: `iPad Air` doesn't seem to work anymore, `iPad Pro (9.7-inch)` works

Answer (score 7):

You can specify the device the simulator should run with the --simulator flag, followed by the device name as a string. The default is "iPhone X". If you wish to run your app on an iPad Pro (9.7-inch), run

> react-native run-ios --simulator="iPad Pro (9.7-inch)".

You can check all your available devices

> xcrun simctl list devices

from the console.
Refer this:
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/running-on-simulator-ios

Answer (score 4):

Short answer is that you can't change it since the default simulator value is encoded in [runIOS.js](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/local-cli/runIOS/runIOS.js), particularly in [line 35](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/local-cli/runIOS/runIOS.js#L35) with `default: 'iPhone 6'`, meaning that if `--simulator` flag is not specified, it will always be iPhone 6.

From here I think you have 4 options:

1. Keep using `--simulator` flag.
2. Create an alias for `react-native run-ios --simulator 'iPad 2'`, something like `alias rnrii=react-native run-ios --simulator 'iPad 2'`, which is essentially a shortcut for the command.
3. Find runIOS.js locally (probably somewhere in `/usr/local/lib/node_modules` and modify default simulator option
4. Come up with some local react-native-cli configurations and try getting it merged into `facebook/react-native` repo.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure to close your simulator first

You can open the Xcode project from {YourApp}/ios/{YourApp}.xcodeproj

Then select the default simulator you want and then build the application it will run on the new simulator.

then you can use react-native run-ios and it will run on the new default one!

[image]